# Warning before accepting name change

Tags: feature-request

After editing a golf code style answer I decided to change my display name to make a stupid joke by taking a name (and an avatar) close to a famous golf pro player. So far so good, but when I decided to get back my usual name few hours later there was a red message :

[image]

So my question is :

- Is it possible to put a red warning before to accept a name change telling something like : 
  "Display name may only be changed once every 30 days. Are you sure that this is what you want ? Check the spelling before to press ok."?
- Is it possible to allow the changes in the first 24h, for example, in a way to be able to correct some misspelling?

N.B. The positive side of the story is that I won't participate in TeX.SX in the next 30 days. And I needed a cure ...

Comment: maybe better suited for meta.stackexchange.com as it is not specific to tex.se?

Comment: (I hope the sun glasses are drawn with Tikz :)

Comment: That's why one should only use one's true name. ;-) I think @samcarter and CarLaTeX will agree on that ;-)

Comment: @marmot ... until you find out that car mats are made in latex...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question should be moved to meta.stackexchange.com, because it is not specific to TeX.SE, as samcarter said.

Comment: @Tikzer Maybe if you ask the moderators they can change it at once (However I like Tikzer Woods :):):)).

Comment: For French people [MajesTikZ](https://static5.wall-art.de/out/pictures/generated/product/1/780_780_80/ao1025-wandtattoo_majestix_web.jpg) may also be an option ;-)

Comment: @marmot Why is this off-topic exactly? It seems very on-topic to me and to highlight something of a problem: people shouldn't be stuck with a typo for 30 days!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Why is this off-topic?

Comment: I don't know what this is intended to prevent, but 24 hours might be too long. However, surely 5 minutes or so would be very reasonable and certainly a warning should be given before the first change, in case somebody is changing to something specific to some special occasion or something without realising they'll be stuck as 'TurkeyTriumph!' until February ....

Comment: @cfr Please read my previous comment, and samcarter's one.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I already read them. Re. samcarter's comment. I don't think that makes it off-topic. We have other topics which are by no means specific to TeX SE and not everyone is going to feel comfortable posting on meta meta. Re. your comment: that doesn't make it off-topic. The fact that moderators can do X does not make a feature request to enable users to do X invalid. You might think the request is a bad idea, but that doesn't make it off-topic. It seems to me a rather good idea: it's surely ridiculous for mods to have to correct silly typos. If you oppose the request, say so or downvote.

Comment: @cfr For my previous comment I intended my second one.

Comment: @CarLaTeX But people haven't voted to move it anywhere. People have voted to close it. And anyway, this is completely inconsistent with out treatment of other topics on TeX's meta.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I only have one vote and I used it already :(.

Comment: An Avatar and a name identifies a thing. "@userXyZ You just asked the same question as yesterday, again without a MWE. Please edit your question by adding an MWE instead of asking new questions." Of course, people can create multiple accounts to ask the same *poor* question, still *I* am  against frequent name changes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it is a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45200/237989